# steganography riddle

Tags: visual, steganography

I have this image of Lena in BMP format, which consist a secret message: [image]

And I got this hint for this riddle:[image]

My initial thought was going over the image row by row and get the LSB of pixels in indices that are triangular numbers (1,3,6,10,...,261726 since my image is 512x512 -> 262144 pixels) but unfortunately I don't get any readable message this way.

Does anyone have a creative idea on how to interpret this hint?

Additional info is that I have also tried to compare the image to the original Lena in BMP format:[image]

and I saw that the differences between the pixels are 0, +1 or +2 in the "challenge image" compared to the original one - still don't have a solid conclusion on how this info could help.. going over the LSB with the differences didn't provide ant readable result as well.

your ideas will be appriciated!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Unfortunately, proper attribution is required to reopen your question.